# How to recive an email with attachment

Tags: python, email

I was asked to recive an email using any coding language ( I know java and C but python will be much easier I think but I hope someone can help me choose) then look for the word "cat" inside the body of the email then run the python file attachment which is attached to the mail and send back the output of the file to the sender if the word cat is in the message ( if the word wasnt there or the file returned an exception then return the the problem ) here is what I did so far :

```
import email
import imaplib
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

def send_email():
    sender_email = 'momo@gmail.com'
    password = '123456789'
    rec_email ="koko@gmail.com"
    message = input(str("enter your message below : "))

    server= smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(sender_email, password )
    print("login success")
    server.sendmail(sender_email , rec_email, message )
    print("Email has been sent to " , rec_email )


def recive_and_check():
    EMAIL = 'nono@gmail.com'
    PASSWORD = '123456789'
    SERVER = 'imap.gmail.com'

    # connect to the server and go to its inbox
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SERVER)
    mail.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)

    mail.select("inbox")

#I used several tutorials on youtube from here don't really understand what I wrote

    status, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')

    inbox_item_list = data[0].split()

    most_recent = inbox_item_list[-1]
    oldest = inbox_item_list [0]
    email_data = mail.fetch(most_recent,'(RFC822)')
    raw_email = email_data[0][1].decode("utf-8")
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    email_message: EmailMessage = email.message_from_bytes(envelope, _class=EmailMessage)

    for email_message_part in email_message.walk():
        if email_message_part.is_attachment():
            Run(email_message_part)
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: I had come to a point where I inside the email but I need to download the attachment and run it and save the output . would you like to help me with that ?